# Case Fan Cable Splitters

Tags: fan, splitter

I have two 120mm case fans that I'm trying to hook up to a singular 3-pin Male connector.  I need a Y-Splitter that has two 4 Pin (male) and one 3 pin (female).

Does such an item exist?

Comment: You should only split the 12V of a Molex connector.  If there's a sensor wire (for RPM or fan lock), then you shouldn't try to split (or share) that connection.

Answer (score 1):

Before you go any further, you should check the current limitations for that connector on your motherboard to make sure it can handle the combined amperage of two fairly large fans.  It probably can, but this is good practice if the information is available.

Assuming that is acceptable, or that you are willing to take a chance anyway, you will only need a normal 3-pin to 3-pin splitter [like this one](http://www.startech.com/Cables/Computer-Power/Internal/6-in-TX3-Fan-Power-Splitter-Cable~TX3SPLITTER).  The trick is in [how you plug it in](http://www.allpinouts.org/index.php/Motherboard_(CPU)_4_Pin_Fan).

[image: connecting a 4-pin fan to a 3-pin header]
The fourth pin on each fan's connector should hang off to the appropriate side of the pins on the splitter, as shown in the picture.  The speed control wire on pin 4 will usually be a blue wire, whereas the other side (pin 1 ground wire) will usually be a black wire.  The connectors are designed to work this way.  That's why there isn't a plastic guard on the sides of the connector.  The fourth pin is only needed for boards that can control the fan speed.

Please note that on the adapter, having two fans share the Y will report their combined fan speed, since each fan sends a pulse on each revolution.  Sometimes they will spin in sync where they are both pulsing at the same time, which would occasionally make the reading closer to the speed of a single fan or even lower.  This could confuse your fan monitoring program, but it is easily cured.  If you only want to monitor one fan, clip pin 3 on one of the ends of the Y (since it's cheaper to replace than the fan if you change your mind).  This way it will only report the speed of the other fan.

Comment: i'm curious and a bit rusty. When, if ever,  is the 4th pin for reporting the RPM to the MBRD, and when , if ever, is it for speed control?  Is it that there is just a sensor of RPM pin when it's 3pins. And when it's 4 pins, is it  that there is then a sensor pin and fan control pin?

Comment: The 3rd pin reports the RPM to the motherboard.  The fourth pin is for speed control using a controlled pulse signal from the computer.  For fans that only have 2 or 3 pins, the speed is adjusted the old-fashioned way by adjusting the supply voltage on pin 2.  Wikipedia has a good article explaining the details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_fan_control